# get params querys from get request php

Tags: php

I send  this request

```
http://localhost/login.php/auth/SigIn?username=1
```

[image]

and my code to get values is this

```
 public function SigInAction(){
        $strErrorDesc = '';
        $requestMethod = $_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"];
        $arrQueryStringParams = $this->getQueryStringParams();
        if (strtoupper($requestMethod) == 'GET') {
            try {
                $p_userName = "";
                $p_password = "";
                
                if (isset($arrQueryStringParams['username']) && $arrQueryStringParams['username']) {
                $p_userName = $arrQueryStringParams['username'];                    
                }
} catch (Error $e) {
                $strErrorDesc = $e->getMessage().'Something went wrong! Please contact support.';
                $strErrorHeader = 'HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error';
            }
        } else {
            $strErrorDesc = 'Method not supported';
            $strErrorHeader = 'HTTP/1.1 422 Unprocessable Entity';
        } 
}
```

and my method getQueryStringParams is

```
protected function getQueryStringParams()
    {
        return parse_str($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], $query);
    }
```

when intent acces to variable i have null value

```
echo $arrQueryStringParams
```

[image]

try this ,

```
$p_userName = $_GET['username']
```

[image]

Comment: There is the global `$_GET` array, which is an associative array with query param as index associated with its value. So you can just get you `username` like this: `$_GET['username']`. Do note that you should check if it's not null.

Comment: mm not working, you can me more context,i update

Comment: `return parse_str($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], $query);` makes no sense. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php: _"Return Values: No value is returned."_ The second parameter gets passed by reference, and that is what the result will be stored into. You need to return `$query`, after this function has executed.

Comment: But simply accessing `$_GET['username']` _should_ also work here, so if it doesn't, something else must be going on. Have you verified what `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` actually contains yet?

Comment: What if you var_dump $_GET?

Comment: @CBroe yous comment help my, please responses my questions to yours points

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```html
protected function getQueryStringParams()
    {
        return $_GET;
    }
```

Comment: mm not working, you can me more context, i update

Comment: Are you using a framework?

Comment: i use visual studio code nothing else

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using `$_REQUEST`. It gets not only GET, but even POST, PUT etc.

You can get the details [here.](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_superglobals_request.asp)

Code will look something like this:

```
protected function getQueryStringParams()
{
    return $_REQUEST;
}
```